# TFS Build Server - Not running tests after upgrade

Tags: tfsbuild

After upgrading to TFS 2017 (from 2015), our unit tests have stopped working. It does not throw an error, it simply doesn't find any tests even though they are in in the project. This use to work fine before the upgrade.

The screenshot shows all the steps in our process, everything passes. The only problem is it doesn't pick up the existing tests.
[image]

Extract from the log:

2017-08-17T15:40:04.2990543Z ##[warning]No results found to publish.

2017-08-17T15:40:04.3070586Z ##[section]Finishing: Test Assemblies **\Release*test*.dll;-:**\obj**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you updated the build agent correspondingly? If not, please update the agent version to match TFS 2017, then try it again.

You can also try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Try to run the test locally in command line to check if the test
  results exist there.
- If you use runsettings file, In your runsettings file, comment out
  the ResultsDirectory tag under the RunConfiguration section.
- Manually select the Test platform version, eg: select **Visual Studio
  2015** instead of the **Latest**
- Manually specify the vs test location, Path to vstest.console.exe
- Try to use **MSTEST** step instead of VStest

If that still not work, please share the entire test log here for further troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Have check it all and it led me to the problem.

Some one added the following to the Build tasks. The outdir option put the binaries in a different place and hence the test running correctly found nothing. 

/p:DeployOnBuild=true;OutDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"

To test I changed the Search Folder to $(build.artifactstagingdirectory), and success.